# Need help simplifying my code on poker evaluation

Tags: c#

I am currently creating a poker evaluator that compares the hand from multiple players and decide who the winner is. However, the method for the actual comparison and tie-breaking turns out to be much more work than it should. Is there any way I can perhaps simplify my code? Since I am not posting all of the source code I will discuss the functionality for some of the methods called within:

int HandEval(Card[] hand) takes an array of cards and return an int which symbolizes the score of the hand(ie. three of a kind will have a higher score than one pair)

int GetHighCard(Card[] hand) takes an array of cards and return the rank of the high card used for tie-breaking.(ie. in the case of three of a kind, the rank of one of these three kinds will be returned)

```
 public void FindWinner()
    {
        int maxScore = 0;
        int maxRank = 0;
        List<String> potentialWinners = new List<string>();
        List<Card[]> candHand = new List<Card[]>();

        Dictionary<string, Card[]> deckTable = new Dictionary<string, Card[]>();
        Dictionary<string, int> scoreTable = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        Dictionary<string, int> highTable = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        //place each player to deckTable which holds the player name and their hand
        //place each player to scoreTable which holds the player name and the score of their hand
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
        {
            deckTable.Add(players[i].GetName(), players[i].GetSorted());
            scoreTable.Add(players[i].GetName(), HandEval(players[i].GetSorted()));

        }

        //display the player name and the score of their hand
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in scoreTable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, +pair.Value);
        }

        //find the max score of the current game
        foreach (var kvp in scoreTable)
        {
            if (kvp.Value > maxScore)
            {
                maxScore = kvp.Value;
            }
        }

        //display the max score
        Console.WriteLine("The maximum score is " + maxScore);

        //for all players with the max score, add them to the potential winners list
        foreach (var kvp in scoreTable)
        {
            if (kvp.Value == maxScore)
            {
                potentialWinners.Add(kvp.Key);
            }
        }

        //if there are more than one potential winner, run the tie-break checks
        if (potentialWinners.Count > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Potential winners include: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < potentialWinners.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("" + potentialWinners[i] + "");
            }

            //add the name of the potential winners and the rank of the high card as a key value pair to highTable
            for (int i = 0; i < potentialWinners.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (deckTable.ContainsKey(potentialWinners[i]))
                {
                    Card[] cHand = deckTable[potentialWinners[i]];
                    highTable.Add(potentialWinners[i], GetHighCard(cHand));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Displaying potential winners with their high card rank.");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in highTable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            //find the max rank of high card from all potential winners
            foreach (var kvp in highTable)
            {
                if (kvp.Value > maxRank)
                {
                    maxRank = kvp.Value;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The final winner after tie-breaking is");

            //display the winner(s) with the highest rank of card
            foreach (var kvp in highTable)
            {
                if (kvp.Value == maxRank)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("" + kvp.Key + "");
                }
            }
        }
        //if there is only one potential winner, display the name
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The final winner is");
            Console.WriteLine(potentialWinners[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This would be better on CodeReview

Comment: It's unusual to remove your question from stack overflow. The idea is to create some sort of database which topics are easily found by search engines. Don't be ashamed or anything like that for some old code, nobody was born as an experienced coder. Every time I look at some old code of mine - maybe only a year old - I find a ton of things that I would do far better now.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest mistake is to ignore what kind of language you are using. Your style is imperative, not object oriented.

What you want to do is to create classes to handle those things, like cardHand or scoreTable. Then you give them methods like getBestHand.
The part of the code in which you print out stuff should look something like this pseudo-code:

print "The winner is " + table.getBestHand.getPlayer.name

that is, without any for each loop or the like in that part of the code. You want to separate logic and output. Usually it's a good sign when a single function or method has the size of not more than half the screen (exceptions occur of course). Take everything that you could describe in a single word but has more than five lines of code and make a method out of it.

For this isolated example, this will of course produce more code, but I suppose that even in a poker game, having proper classes will already pay out. If not in amount of code, then at least in readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < potentialWinners.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("" + potentialWinners[i] + "");
}

//add the name of the potential winners and the rank of the high card as a key value pair to highTable


for (int i = 0; i < potentialWinners.Count(); i++)
{
    if (deckTable.ContainsKey(potentialWinners[i]))
    {
        Card[] cHand = deckTable[potentialWinners[i]];
        highTable.Add(potentialWinners[i], GetHighCard(cHand));
    }
}
```

You are basically calling the same for loop 2 times, you could bring the

```
Console.WriteLine("" + potentialWinners[i] + "");
```

in the for loop after it... also pls remove the (`""`) out of your Console WriteLine´s its doing basically nothing but making your Code slower

the same is said for these loops

```
foreach (var kvp in highTable)
```

and

```
foreach (var kvp in scoreTable)
```

simple things to make your code smaler and more efficient

Greetings

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, I will take a closer look now. I knew something was wrong with my code:)